# How to import css by specific directory

Tags: vue.js

This is my vue project directory.

```
src/
   /assets/css/aa.css
   /assets/css/bb.css
   /assets/css/cc.css 
   /views/aa/index.vue
   /views/aa/page.vue
   /views/bb/index.vue
   /views/bb/page.vue
   /views/cc/index.vue
   /views/cc/page.vue
```

I want to import aa.css file only /aa/index.vue.

Also import bb.css file only /bb/index.vue.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

In those files use `<style>` section and set `scoped`.
In fact, you'll have something like

```css
<style scoped>
   here you import goes
</style>
```

Read more about Vue CSS scopes [here](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html)